# Using private/public keys for external API integration tests with PHPunit

Tags: php, api, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to write some integration tests for my web app which uses the Xero API. I'm using PHP unit and Laravel 5.3 framework. Whenever I run the tests though I get a 500 error which I'm guessing has something to do with the private/public keys not being found or possibly my API keys in my `.env` file not being found. If I run the application in the browser I get the expected result, no errors.

I have three files (`ca-bundle.crt`, `privatekey.pem` and `publickey.cer`) which are located in the directory `certs/Xero` as well as two API keys which are located in my `.env` file. All of these are needed for the API call.

My test file has the following code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class XeroGatewayTest extends TestCase
{
  use DatabaseTransactions;

  /** @test */ 
  public function it_returns_a_list_of_invoices_for_a_customer()
  {
    $customer = factory(App\Customer::class)->create();

    $this->get('/api/changes/invoices/'.$customer->id);

    $this->assertResponseOk();
    $this->seeJson();
  }
}
```

The API endpoint calls a method in the `InvoiceController` to retrieve the invoice details for that customer.

I have a Xero config file (`xero.php`) located in the `config` directory which has the following:

```
<?php

return [

  'xero' => [
    'core_version'    => '2.0',
    'payroll_version' => '1.0',
    'file_version'    => '1.0',
  ],

  'oauth' => [
    'callback' => 'oob',

    'consumer_key'    => env('XERO_KEY'),
    'consumer_secret' => env('XERO_SECRET'),

    'rsa_private_key' => file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../certs/Xero/privatekey.pem'),
    'rsa_public_key'  => file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/../certs/Xero/publickey.cer'),
  ],

  'curl' => [
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'The Builder',
    CURLOPT_CAINFO    => '../certs/Xero/ca-bundle.crt',
  ]

];
```

The config file is passed into a custom `XeroServiceProvider` class in its constructor. The class is then used to make the API calls.

Now when I run the application in the browser, I get the result I want (a json object with the invoice details of the customer). However when I run the test in the terminal I get:

```
1) XeroGatewayTest::it_returns_a_list_of_invoices_for_a_customer
Expected status code 200, got 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php:663
/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/integration/invoicing/XeroGatewayTest.php:18

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

I've also updated my `composer.json` file to include the following:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.16",
        "calcinai/xero-php": "^1.3"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "files": [
            "certs/Xero/ca-bundle.crt",
            "certs/Xero/privatekey.pem",
            "certs/Xero/publickey.cer",
        ],
    },
...
```

Any help / pointers would be greatly appreciated, many thanks.

Comment: Could you show the whole response via `$this->dump()`?

Comment: Aha cracked it! After showing the response with `$this->dump()` I could see there was an issue with the `ca-bundle.crt` file. I just needed to add `__DIR__` to that filepath too and it's all good now. Thanks for your help